# How to align multiline text in react native

Tags: react-native, text, alignment, multiline

In my screen, I need to split the text into column view and need to align the right side text with the left side text. also, need to show the whole text line by line. Tested with giving some height, width, position: absolute but didn't work. Any idea how to solve this?

I'll post my current code and screenshot for your ref.

Many thanks for your help

```
   <View style={styles.twoCol}>

     <View style={styles.leftField}>
       <Text style={styles.leftFieldTitle}>Location:</Text>
      </View>

     <View style={styles.locationRightSide}>
       <Text style={styles.rightFieldTitle}>{location}</Text>
     </View>

   </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

     twoCol: {
           alignItems: 'center',
           flexDirection: 'row',
           marginTop: 25,
         },
      leftField: {
            alignItems: 'flex-end',
            width: '25%',
        },  
       leftFieldTitle: {
            fontWeight: '700',
            color: 'black'
        },

        },
        locationRightSide: {
            width: '70%',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            paddingLeft: 10
        },
      rightFieldTitle: {
            fontSize: RF(2.8),
            color: 'black'
        },
        )}
```

[image: this is how it shows currently]

Comment: run your code in expo and link it to your post
and i will fix it for u

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!! Thanks everyone! 
[image: after the issue fixed]

```
<View style={{
                                padding: 10,
                                flexDirection: "row",
                                marginLeft: 10,
                                marginRight: 5,
                                marginTop: 5,
                                marginBottom: 3,
                                justifyContent: "flex-start",
                                width: '95%',
                            }} >
                                <View style={{
                                    position: 'absolute',
                                    marginTop: 10
                                }}>
                                    <Text style={styles.leftFieldTitle}>Location:</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{ marginLeft: '26%' }}>
                                    <Text style={styles.rightFieldTitle}>{location}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
```